# Chinese Chengyu (Idiom): Refute somebody with his own argument

Tags: vocabulary, usage, classical-chinese, idioms, chengyu

Is there a Chinese Idiom for

"Refute somebody with his own argument"?

I thought this is not quite the same as "self-contradictory" 自相矛盾.

Thank you.

Comment: How about `以其人之道还治其人之身`?

Comment: Also “以牙还牙，以眼还眼”

Comment: In martial arts, "以彼之道, 還施彼身"  ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe 以子之矛，攻子之盾 is the answer, I couldn't find another alternative.

[Description on Baidu Baike](http://baike.baidu.com/view/95735.htm)

Comment: Thank you! Although 自相矛盾 and 以子之矛，攻子之盾 originate from the same story, they don't mean the same things, right? 自相矛盾 means self-contradictory, while 以子之矛，攻子之盾 means "Refute somebody with his own argument." Am I correct?

Comment: @ChristmasBunny Yes. That's it.